# Converting two LocalTime objects into a Duration object

Tags: java, jodatime, datediff

Joda is a must as Java SE8 is not available in this environment.

How do I go about finding the difference in hours between two `LocalTime` objects, to store as a `Duration`? Tried the following with no luck:

```
LocalTime startTime = new LocalTime(8, 0);
LocalTime endTime = new LocalTime(16, 0);

Period shiftDuration = new Period(0, 
endTime.getHourOfDay() - startTime.getHourOfDay(), 0, 0);

System.out.println(shiftDuration.getHours()); // expected 8, get 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specifically the number of hours between those 2 `LocalTime` instances, you can use the `org.joda.time.Hours` class:

```
LocalTime startTime = new LocalTime(8, 0);
LocalTime endTime = new LocalTime(16, 0);

int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(startTime, endTime).getHours();
```

The result will be `8`.

You can also use a `org.joda.time.Period`:

```
Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime);
System.out.println(period.getHours()); // 8
```

The result is also `8`.

The difference between them is that `Hours` rounds the value, but `Period` doesn't. Example:

```
// difference between 08:00 and 16:30
LocalTime startTime = new LocalTime(8, 0);
LocalTime endTime = new LocalTime(16, 30);

Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime);
System.out.println(period); // PT8H30M
System.out.println(period.getHours()); // 8
System.out.println(period.getMinutes()); // 30

int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(startTime, endTime).getHours();
System.out.println(hours); // 8
```

While the `Period` keeps all the fields (8 hours and 30 minutes), the `Hours` takes care only about the hours and discard the other fields.

Comment: Very informative, you actually answered a minor problem I was having yesterday too. Thanks very much for sharing your expertise!

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the values in wrong arguments. Try this:

```
LocalTime startTime = new LocalTime(8, 0);
    LocalTime endTime = new LocalTime(16, 0);

    Period shiftDuration = new Period(endTime.getHourOfDay() - startTime.getHourOfDay(), 0, 0, 0);

    System.out.println(shiftDuration.getHours());
```

According to [JODA documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html):

```
Period(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis) 
          Create a period from a set of field values using the standard set of fields.
```